# Creating a bitmap image from 3 byte arrays

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I would like to create bitmap image from three arrays of bytes:
`Range_R` represents red color.
`Range_G` represents green color.
`Range_B` represents blue.
How can I do this in android studio?

This my code but I'm not sure because the resulted image has bad different colors than the original image.

```
for (int i = 0; i < srcImg.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < srcImg.getHeight(); j++) {
            int pixel = srcImg.getPixel(i, j);
            byte Red = (byte) Color.red(Range_R[i][j]);
            byte Green = ((byte) Color.green(Range_G[i][j]));
            byte Blue = (byte) Color.blue(Range_B[i][j]);
            int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
            newimage.setPixel(i, j, argb(alpha,Red, Green, Blue));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Color.red()/green()/blue()` here. Those are for extracting byte-sized values out of a larger bitfield (`int/long`). You've stated that these are `byte` arrays, therefor the values are already of the correct size, and likely, scale.

Also, you should make sure that `Red`, `Green`, and `Blue` are each in the range [0..255]. Some of the array members are likely negative; in this case, you will have to increase their value by 256:

```
if(Red < 0)
    Red += 256;
```

...and so forth. This is to meet the input specification of [`argb()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: if we add 256 to negative values that will change the value this image must have the same image because it contain hidden message..can you help me with full code

Comment: Have you tried it? The 256 is to correct the value from a signed, negative `byte` to an (effectively unsigned) `int`. The documentation for `argb()` clearly states that the results are undefined in the case of negative values.

Comment: now i tried it , i mean adding 256 to any negative value but no change

Comment: thanks for your interest , in fact i feel it difficult to understand